# How to have a checklist to show your athletes?

Tags: gymnastics

I want a checklist that I can show, but I do no want those who are not achieving as well not to fell left out. I want this for a gymnastics class, so that they can see how well they are doing.

Answer (score 1):

Include a bunch of easy-to-achieve items so that everyone has some things checked off. Depending on the age of your athletes, they might realize that some of the items are really just filler/nonsense.

If that's still not enough, then do the checklists on separate pieces of paper that you hand out and go over with each athlete individually.

I'm not super familiar with gymnastics, but a list might look something like this.

- On time and ready to go at start of every class
- Appropriate attitude
- Helpful with other students
- Puts away equipment at end of class (?)
- Warm up (?)
- Complete easy activity 1
- Complete easy activity 2
- Complete easy activity 3
- Complete moderate activity 1
- Complete moderate activity 2
- Complete moderate activity 3
- Complete difficult activity 1
- Complete difficult activity 2
- Complete difficult activity 3

The idea is that even your "worst" students will have half the checklist done.

Also, one other thought may be to focus (at least partially) on improvement rather than achievement. So even if they're bad at some item on the checklist, if they're making progress, it can be encouraging for them to hear that that's recognized.